# How to rename files by removing a number and a fixed string from begin and keep just number before file extension?

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

I have some files as listed below and I want to use a batch script to rename these files by removing a number and a fixed string from begin and keep just number before file extension.

```
Original name       New name
----------------    --------
1_Asset_28.png   -> 28.png
212_Asset_2.png  -> 2.png
1_Asset_288.png  -> 288.png
89_Asset_117.png -> 117.png
```

The goal is to delete first number and `_Asset_`.

I have been searching for a while, but still don't know how to do this.

How can this file renaming task be done with a batch file?

Answer (score 1):

Heres one option for you:

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In ("*_Asset_*.png") Do (Set "fN=%%A"
    Call Ren "%%A" "%%fN:*_Asset_=%%")
```

Comment: Error , he print : Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.

Comment: Are you aware that this must either be run from the directory containing the `.png` files or the full path to that directory prepended to the wildcard name inside the parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the input by the underscore and use the last token.
When you cannot use PowerShell you can use the `for /f` tokenizer, like this:

```
set input=1_Asset_28.png
rem split by underscore
for /f "tokens=3 delims=_" %%a in ("%input%") do set "output=%%a"

echo output %output%"
```

will print

```
output "28.png"
```

Comment: A good answer from the perspective of using the underscore as a delimiter but the question did clearly specify that the user wants to process multiple files. So you would need to adjust your `FOR /F` command to fully answer the question.

Comment: @Squashman you are right, I missed that point. There is already a better answr now from Compo

Answer (score -1):

Try this PowerShell command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *Asset*.png | %{ Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName $_.FullName.Substring($_.FullName.LastIndexOf('_') + 1) }
```